# Derive properties as per the requirement...?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

So, I have 3 fields/properties. Say, they are, paramA, paramB, paramC. And I’ve three classes as Class A, Class B, Class C. 
Requirement is to use:

```
•   paramA, paramB in Class A
•   paramA, paramC in Class B
•   paramB, paramC in Class D
```

Is there any way to declare all these 3 properties in a common place and derive in the A,B,C classes as per the requirement....?

**UPDATE**
Please find some more details of the requirement:
The real requirement is:
There is a table ‘Que Table’ in database which is having following fields

```
•   bool IsQb
•   bool IsOverride
•   string Identifier
•   string userlogin
•   FolderName
```

Following model classes are using for create/update/delete data in ‘Que Table’.

```
•   CreateQue class
•   UpdateQue class 
•   DeleteQue class
```

CreateQue class only requires the properties:IsQb, IsOverride,UserLogin, FolderName 
UpdateQue class only requires the properties: IsQb, IsOverride, Identifier, UserLogin, FolderName 
And DeleteQue class only requires: Identifier property.

The code for the model classes are:

```
public class CreateQue 
    {
        public bool IsQb { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverride { get; set; }
        public string  userlogin { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
    }

    public class UpdateQue
    {
        public bool IsQb { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverride { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public string userlogin { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeleteQue
    {
        public string userlogin { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }
```

So, is there any pattern/architecture out there to declare all those properties in a single place and derive as per the requirement in those model classes....?  
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean by "requirement is to use"... It would help if you could give more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Make a static class that exposes 3 properties and then use those across your project?

Comment: At first glance this leans towards a class with the params declared as `virtual`, but you should provide more info here. You might also have a flawed design.

Comment: How about creating a single `Que` class and associated `Create`, `Update` and `Delete` *functions*? Why do you need to use separate classes for that?

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet; thanks but these model classes are used in web api interfaces. 3 interfaces(Create/Update/Delete) will be available to the outside world as service contracts. The model classes are used as input parameters in those APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you need to do as we can't see your requirements. You could use interfaces:

```
public interface IHasPropertyA
{
    string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasPropertyB
{
    string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IHasPropertyA, IHasPropertyB
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This would work due to the multiple inheritance restriction in .NET, e. you cant combine A+B, A+C and B+C without using interfaces.